# Saving variables and booleans in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, variables, timer, save

I'm new to iOS development, currently in the process of creating my first app which its core function is a timer

I have a few different variables (for example start time of timer) and a boolean of whether the timer is running or not.

Is there a way where I can save the timer start time or boolean values even when the app is closed?

I'm using NSDate to store the start time and comparing the current time to this in order to produce a value of time passed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/index.html https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/iPhoneTasks/iPhoneTasks.html

Answer (score 3):

***Swift 3.x***

**Set and get the Date object**

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(Date(), forKey: "lastDate")
UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "lastDate") as? Date
```

**Set and get the Bool object**

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "isOn")
UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isOn")
```

Comment: The boolean getter is wrong. It's `UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isOn")`

Comment: Yes, you can say but due to Bool you can typecast also

Comment: And, also i am update the answer thanks for remind me

Comment: @vadian in my opinion it is better to retrieve a boolean value using the getter returning an `Any`, since the boolean getter returns `false` even if the key doesn't exist, while the `Any` getter returns nil in this case. And you can cast the results of the getter returning `Any` to bool safely.

Comment: @DávidPásztor A boolean value is supposed to have two states: `true` and `false` (not *maybe* aka `nil)`. In almost all cases `false` can be treated as *no value*. If you really need `nil` as a third state use another type. And  remember: A non-optional type can never cause a crash.

Comment: @vadian what I am trying to say is that if you try to get a value corresponding to a boolean from `UserDefaults` that is not yet stored there, you still get a meaningful value, namely `false`. This in my opinion is quite misleading, hence I prefer to use the retrieval of the optional `Any` value and casting it to a non-optional boolean. This way you only get a meaningful value from `UserDefaults` if there actually was a meaningful value stored.

Comment: @DávidPásztor Apple recommends to **register** default values for all keys in `UserDefaults`. That's the reason why all scalar types return non-optional values for convenience.

Comment: @vadian thanks for the info, that's good to know. However, for me it's still better to use the casting approach, storing default values just doesn't make sense for me in all scenarios.

Comment: Guys, basically we can say it depends on situation..!!!