# Whys isn't my boolean user defaults value being saved until the scene Is loaded again?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have a user defaults for the key sound. I have it switch between the two when the sound button is clicked. Why isn't the value saving until after I leave the scene? If I click on my settings button it will shah up as the wrong value but if I go to another scene and come back it will show the correct value.

Sorry if this is confusing, any help is appreciated.

*Here is my code*

Here is where I declare the variable:

```
    var sound = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "sound")
```

**View did load:**

```
let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
let appDefaults = ["sound" : true]
userDefaults.register(defaults: appDefaults)
```

**Touches Began**

```
if node.name == "settingsSound" {

        clicked()

        if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "sound") == true {

                UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "sound")
                settingsSound.texture? = SKTexture(imageNamed: "settingsSoundOffButton")

        }

        else if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "sound") == false {

                UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "sound")
                settingsSound.texture? = SKTexture(imageNamed: "settingsSoundOnButton")

       is                      
}
```

*And the function being called when I press settings:*

```
if sound == true {
        settingsSound = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "settingsSoundOnButton")
    }

    else if sound == false {
        settingsSound = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "settingsSoundOffButton")
    }
```

Here us my clicked function that just plays the sound:

```
   func clicked() {

    if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "sound") == true {
        run(backClick)

    }
}
```

Comment: `bool(forKey:)` returns a non optional Bool so using `== true` is redundant https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1416388-bool also no need to write anything at your else keyword `if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "sound") { ... } else {`

Comment: the same applies to `if sound == true {` if sound it is not an optional Bool

Comment: @the4kman synchronize only forces it to write to disk. The value it is already available at memory

Comment: Are you sure your button is in the right state to begin with?  Your texture may say on, but your state may be off.  we need to see where you assign your `sound` variable

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45351787/saving-variables-and-booleans-in-swift-3/45351936#45351936

Comment: can you post also your clicked method?

Comment: Yes, I just added the clicked method and where I declared sound

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to negate the defaults value you can use the prefix operator "!" when setting your new value. No need to use a condition at all. And you can use the ternary operator to compose your image name. You should also remove the ? suffix when setting your texture:

```
let sound = !UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "sound")
UserDefaults.standard.set(sound, forKey: "sound")
settingsSound.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "settingsSound" + (sound ? "On" : "Off") + "Button")
```